# Can't Access wamp server (localhost) on my android device

Tags: android, apache, wamp, wampserver

I am developing a responsive website and i want to check it on my android devices (mobile, tablet).
I am trying to access my server in the mobile browser's window using my ip (192.168.1.100).
I have tried various methods discussed here like 
[access-localhost-from-mobile-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401235/access-localhost-from-mobile-phone)

I have also edited my apache config file as suggested but nothing working.
No matter what i do, i get 
Forbidden, you don't have permission  to access / on this server.
I am running apache 2.4

I have also tried

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

then

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require ip 255.255.255 (my subnet)
</Directory>
```

then

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require ip 192.168.1.100(my IPv4)
</Directory>
```

Nothing works for me...

Comment: post the code where connecting to server.

Comment: i am trying to access with by typing my ip on mobile's browser. it's 192.168.1.100

Comment: Have you tried disabling your firewall?

Comment: To get this to work, you have to change the listening ip:port to your tablet's ip:port in Apache config... Ahh, and instead of running it on your tablet, why not emulate it with Chrome dev tools? It will give you a list of many more devices as well. And a touch tool too!

Comment: Try it with this options **** Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       -  AllowOverride None -
        Require all granted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably won't be able to access server via "192.168.1.100" even on your computer. Try confirming it by typing the ip address on your PC. I was running into the same issue. Then found the solution.

Basicallly,

"Order Allow,Deny" would not work for apache 2.4

just use 
    **Require all granted** instead.

Thanks to:
[QuantumHive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551840/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

Comment: Can you explain me where to add / modify this code.

Comment: gnganpath "Require all granted" is added inside the <directory "/path/to/website"></directory> tag, either in httpd.conf, or in your vhost configuration if you are using that (also inside a <directory "/path/to/website"></directory>.

Answer (score 0):

In PLEX I was able to add an HTML to previous older versions.
That bug was fixed and the new feature is that you must access the pages via 32400 hardcoded in the system.
Well that did not work as human nature is to type movies.com and the page to open not movie.com:32400 to open it.

I am using version 3.x apache and this issue still exists in the script that the server auto-creates with.  I spent lots of time looking for this GEM of a fix.

On the LOCAL server, things worked great but from any other device on the network, I got the forbidden even with the firewall shut down, and "put online clicked"(wamp).
this simple change fixed it.
Why it is not fixed or even more heavily discussed I have no idea as it took me 3 hours to locate this and 2 minutes to fix the problem.

Working now as expected, but not sure about this error 
(IP 192.168.3.111 for Servername plex is not valid in file c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.39/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. That's what I did:
First, I wrote on my terminal:  ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1
Then, I knew my ipV4.
After that, I change my file.conf (on Mac OS is in /etc/apache2/users) and I deleted the line "Require ....".

Now I have access from my android device to my ipV4 :)